# How to add Room migration from file

Tags: android, migration, inputstream, assert, android-room

Happy New Year for you.

How i can create Room migration by internal project file?
Ex: I have file with sql script in path: `/assets/migrations/10.sql`

I have this method:

```
private static final Migration MIGRATION_9_10 = new Migration(9, 10) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        String scriptId = "10_"+DATABASE_LANGUAGE+".sql";
        Log.d("TEST", "MIGRATE TO 10: " + database.getVersion()+"NME: "+scriptId);
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = DATABASE_CONTEXT.getAssets().open(scriptId);
            Log.d("TEST", "InputStream: " + inputStream.toString());
            database.execSQL(readString(inputStream));
            //db.execSQL(initSql);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        }
    }
};
```

but always this table empty in logs.
How i can do it correct?
Thank you!

Comment: What table you are talking about? What are you log?